# Integral $\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{e^x} \log_e t\cdot \cos^4 t\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, proof-writing

$$F(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{e^x} log_e t\cdot cos^4 t\cdot dt$$

So I tried using Leibniz's rule, by differentiating under the integral

$$\frac{d}{d\alpha}F(x,\alpha)=\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{e^x}\partial_{\alpha}\ log_e t\alpha\cdot cos^4 t\cdot dt$$

However, there were a few problems with finding the initial condition and all that.

Question is to evaluate the integral. This is a high school problem by the way. So please don't post any difficult answers (no offense). Hints would be nice too. And since I struggled with the initial condition (constant of integration) after using Leibniz (Feynman's differentiating under the integral), help with that part alone would be enough.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint: You don't have to find a closed form for the integral

Comment: You probably know the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus)...

Comment: Thanks for responding Maximilian Janisch.  I don't know what closed forms are.

Comment: @AudreyWinters I am saying that you don't have to compute the integral in order to get the derivative

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I kinda thought about that. But I guess I'm not getting it.

Comment: @AudreyWinters explained in the two answers below are methods that make it easy to simplify $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t)\,\mathrm dt $$ even when a simplification of $$\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t)\,\mathrm dt $$  is impossible

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys.

Comment: By the way, since $$\int \exp(\lambda t)\ln(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{e^{\lambda  t} \log (t)}{\lambda }-\frac{\text{Ei}(t \lambda )}{\lambda }$$ by integration by parts, where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), we can actually obtain $$\int \log(t) \cos^4(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{1}{32} (-8 \text{Si}(2 t)-\text{Si}(4 t)-12 t)+\frac{1}{32} \log (t) (12 t+8
   \sin (2 t)+\sin (4 t))$$ where $\text{Si}$ is the [Sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus You have
$$\int_0^{e^x}\log_{e}(t)\cos^4(t)dt=G(e^x)-G(0)$$
where $G$ is an antiderivative of $g(t)=\log_{e}(t)\cos^4(t)$ and thus
$$F(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{e^x}\log_{e}(t)\cos^4(t)dt=\frac{d}{dx}G(e^x)=g(e^x)e^x$$
by the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you Peter Malech. But I've been asked to compute the integral.

Comment: @AudreyWinters It looks like You have to compute $F(x)$, the derivative of the integral and that's what I did, You get the same result by using Leibniz's rule besides, but it is a bit overkill.

Comment: Hey. I got your answer. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: @AudreyWinters You're welcome!

Comment: @AudreyWinters I just changed names from $f$ and $F$ to $g$ and $G$, because $F$ was already given to the function that was to be computed

Answer (score 2):

You've applied the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) wrong. It states (applied to your problem)
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{e^x}\underbrace{\ln t\cos^4 t}_{=f(t)} dt=\underbrace{\ln e^x\cos^4(e^x)}_{f(e^x)}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\Big(e^x\Big)}_{e^x}+\int_0^{e^x} \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\ln t\cos^4 t \Big)}_{=0}dt
\end{align}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hey. Isn't differentiating under the integral (Feynman's Method) same as Leibniz ? Sorry if it isn't. Is the method I used correct though? I'm self taught, so please bear with me. And thank you for responding. I'll try the equation you have posted.

Comment: And how would you differentiate terms dependent on only $t$ with respect to $x$ ? Or does it become zero?

Comment: @AudreyWinters I don't know Feynman's Method but the result must be the same.

Comment: @AudreyWinters For every function g you have $$\frac{d}{dx}\Big(g(t)\Big)=0$$

Comment: Yes, to your edit.